# How can I know the type of argument a method expects?

Tags: ruby, oop

I am trying to understand a code not written by me. How can I know the type of argument a method expects? For example, let's say I have a method:

```
def foo(bar)
  @bar = bar
  @baz = get_user(@bar.user)
end
```

How can I know which object I should send to bar?

Comment: http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/duck_typing.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't know what kind of argument `foo` is waiting to receive, you only know that that object must respond to `user` in your example.

This principle is known as Duck Typing: *With normal typing, suitability is assumed to be determined by an object's type only. In duck typing, an object's suitability is determined by the presence of certain methods and properties (with appropriate meaning), rather than the actual type of the object.*

Comment: So, if many objects belong to User, then, how can I know which object should bar accept? (there is no documentation about what bar should accept)
Isn't there a logical way to know this? How would the compiler know?

Comment: Not specified by the language, you depend on the code now. I imagine you do not have specs either, right? Isn't that method used somewhere else in the code?

Comment: Yes, it was used in someplace else in the code. Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm glad to help, maybe you can accept the answer ;)

Comment: But it is still strange that there is no logical way to know this. Shouldn't it be possible to understand the logic of a code just by reading it?
What if I could't use the search functionality?
How would the compiler know this?

Comment: Well, there's no compiler here, Ruby is an interpreted language and is extremely dynamic, so these kind of behaviors are very common. Ruby is concerned about what an object CAN do rather than what an object IS. That gives you the ability of making your `foo` method work for an arbitrary number of objects of different classes if you want, as long as they respond to `user`. That's powerful and dangerous, but that's how  things work here.